# How to read the messages from rabbitmq other than using listener configuration?

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I am attempting to implement Spring Boot API to fetch the RabbitMQ Messages on demand for asynchronous cart notifications in UI. I already have a working implementation with the help of the Registered listener method. But I am looking for an alternative with or without spring.

```
@Component
public class Receiver {

  private CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

  public void receiveMessage(String message) {
    System.out.println("Received <" + message + ">");
    latch.countDown();
  }

  public CountDownLatch getLatch() {
    return latch;
  }

}
```

Main Class with Reciever Configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MessagingRabbitmqApplication {

  static final String topicExchangeName = "spring-boot-exchange";

  static final String queueName = "spring-boot";

  @Bean
  Queue queue() {
    return new Queue(queueName, false);
  }

  @Bean
  TopicExchange exchange() {
    return new TopicExchange(topicExchangeName);
  }

  @Bean
  Binding binding(Queue queue, TopicExchange exchange) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with("foo.bar.#");
  }

  @Bean
  SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
      MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    container.setQueueNames(queueName);
    container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
    return container;
  }

  @Bean
  MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(Receiver receiver) {
    return new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver, "receiveMessage");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    SpringApplication.run(MessagingRabbitmqApplication.class, args).close();
  }

}
```

My Current Implementation Reference is from: https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/

Comment: Why are you looking for an alternative? If you are using Spring Boot why all the manual configuration and not just use the Spring Boot autoconfiguration and add a single `@RabbitListener`.

Comment: I am implementing a new API to read messages from RabbitMQ **on demand for UI**.

Comment: And why would you need an alternative for that? Just register the listener (or enable it) when needed.

Comment: To show asynchronous cart notifications to UI, We are implementing a new API to retrieve the list of cart action results from RabbitMQ as messages. In the background, we will do the cart actions and post the message to the Queue. Here the Existing UI Architecture is not capable of directly consuming messages from RabbitMQ.

Comment: Push them over websockets to the UI. I don't see what the UI has to do with this. Just use the listener to push it to your UI architecture.

Comment: Thanks, @M.Deinum. I will analyse and implement it with wesockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `RabbitTemplate` API:

```
/**
 * Receive a message if there is one from a specific queue. Returns immediately,
 * possibly with a null value.
 *
 * @param queueName the name of the queue to poll
 * @return a message or null if there is none waiting
 * @throws AmqpException if there is a problem
 */
@Nullable
Message receive(String queueName) throws AmqpException;


/**
 * Receive a message if there is one from a specific queue and convert it to a Java
 * object. Returns immediately, possibly with a null value.
 *
 * @param queueName the name of the queue to poll
 * @return a message or null if there is none waiting
 * @throws AmqpException if there is a problem
 */
@Nullable
Object receiveAndConvert(String queueName) throws AmqpException;
```

And respective docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/#polling-consumer

Comment: Oh! Thanks! This might helps!